# Warn about or avoid integer division (resulting in truncation) in scala

Tags: scala

Consider

```
 1 / 2
```

or

```
 val x: Int = ..
 val n: Int = ..

 x / n
```

Both of these equal .. *0* .. since *integer division* results in truncation.

Also: (this is my typical use case):

```
val averageListSize =  myLists.map(_.length).sum()/myLists.length
```

This has bitten me a few times when it occurs in the middle of long calculations: the first impulse is to check what logical errors have been introduced. Only after some period of debugging and head scratching does the true culprit arise.

Is there any way to expose this behavior  more clearly - e.g. a warning or some (unknown-to-me) language setting or construction that would either alert to or avoid this intermittent scenario?

Comment: This won't answer your question but - as a rule of thumb - when you start doing arithmetics, use `Float`s, `Double`s or even `BigDecimal`s.

Comment: The point is that integers are _generated_ frequently - by API's or especially by _counting_ operations such as cardinality of collections. _I_ did not actually choose to set to _Int_ .. speaking of which I'll update the question to show that use case.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To the best of my knowledge, the Scala compiler does not seem to provide a warning flag that could allow you to raise a warning (documentation [here](https://docs.scala-lang.org/overviews/compiler-options/index.html#Warning_Settings)).

What you could do, however, if you find the effort worth it, is using [Scalafix](https://scalacenter.github.io/scalafix/) and write your own custom rule to detect integer divisions and report warnings about it.

The following is a short example of a rule that can detect integer division on integer literals:

```scala
import scalafix.lint.{Diagnostic, LintSeverity}
import scalafix.patch.Patch
import scalafix.v1.{SemanticDocument, SemanticRule}

import scala.meta.inputs.Position
import scala.meta.{Lit, Term}

class IntDivision extends SemanticRule("IntDivision") {

  override def fix(implicit doc: SemanticDocument): Patch =
    doc.tree.collect({
      case term @ Term.ApplyInfix((_: Lit.Int, Term.Name("/"), Nil, _: List[Lit.Int])) =>
        Patch.lint(new Diagnostic {
          override final val severity: LintSeverity = LintSeverity.Warning
          override final val message: String = "Integer division"
          override final val position: Position = term.pos
        })
    }).asPatch

}
```

When run on the following piece of code:

```scala
object Main {
  def main(args: Array[String]): Unit = {
    println(1 / 2)
  }
}
```

Scalafix will produce the following warning:

```
[warn] /path/to/Main.scala:3:13: warning: [IntDivision] Integer division
[warn]     println(1 / 2)
[warn]             ^^^^^
```

Comment: nice work! v doubtful i'd use it directly but worth upvote/award for the info

Comment: Does Scalafix see inferred types? If not, https://github.com/wartremover/wartremover may be more suitable.

Answer (score 2):

If the `/` op doesn't work for you, make one that does.

```
implicit class Divider[N](numer :N)(implicit evN :Numeric[N]) {
  def /![D](denom :D)(implicit evD :Numeric[D]) :Double =
    evN.toDouble(numer) / evD.toDouble(denom)
}
```

testing:

```
1   /! 2    //res0: Double = 0.5
5.2 /! 2    //res1: Double = 2.6
22  /! 1.1  //res2: Double = 20.0
2.2 /! 1.1  //res3: Double = 2.0
```

Answer (score 1):

Any division operation can result in truncation or rounding. This is most noticeable with `Int` but can happen with all numeric types (e.g. `1.0/3.0`). All data types have a restricted range and accuracy, and so the result of any calculation may be adjusted to fit into the resulting data type.

It is not clear that adding warnings for the specific case of `Int` division is going to help. It is not possible to catch all such issues, and giving warnings in some cases may lead to a false sense of security. It is also going to cause lots of warnings for perfectly valid code.

The solution is to look carefully at any calculations in a program and be aware of the range and accuracy limitations of each operation. If there is any serious computation involved it is a good idea to get a basic grounding in Numerical Analysis.